# Como puedo imprimir un diccionario sin los corchetes

Tags: python, python-3.x

Elemplo

```
Datos ={"001" :{"nombre" :"Juan", "edad" :"23"}
```

Para que se vea así..

```
Nombre: Juan
Edad: 23
```

Yo estoy usando asi

```
Serie =Input ("ingrese serie")
If serie in Datos:
    print(Datos [Serie] )
```

Answer (score 1):

Aquí te dejo el siguiente código:
Entrada:

```
Datos ={"nombre":"Juan", "edad" :"23"}
print('\n'.join("{}: {}".format(k, v) for k, v in Datos.items()))
```

Salida:

```
nombre: Juan
edad: 23
```

Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

En lugar de imprimir el diccionario, imprime separadamente sus campos. Por ejemplo:

```
datos = {"001" :{"nombre" :"Juan", "edad" :"23"} }

serie =input ("Ingrese serie")
if serie in satos:
    print("Nombre:", Datos[serie]["nombre"])
    print("Edad:", Datos[serie]["edad"])
```

(Nota: he pasado a minúscula los nombres de tus variables, pues esa es la recomendación en python, en la que la mayúscula se usa para nombrar clases)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la dificultad del problema está en que "001" es la llave del diccionario. Siendo así, una solución seria:

```
datos = {"001": {"nombre": "Juan", "edad": "23"}}

serie = input("ingrese serie:")
if serie in datos.keys():
    for valor in datos.values():
        for k, v in valor.items():
            print("{}: {}".format(k.title(),v.title()))
```

En el condicional verifico que la serie esté como llave (key) en el diccionario

```
if serie in datos.keys():
```

Luego, guardo en la variable temporaria "valor" los valores del diccionario (values)

```
for valor in datos.values():
```

Ya con esto hecho puedo separar los valores mediante un for, usando la función items() e imprimirlos de la forma que deseo:

```
for k, v in valor.items():
        print("{}: {}".format(k.title(),v.title()))
```